# How to get type(as in request.GetType) of a request message in Service Behavior of WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, servicebehavior, idispatchmessageinspector

I am writing a custom ServiceBehavior which expects me to know the Type of the request message to infer if the message is decorated with a custom attribute.

My Sample Contract could look like:

```
    [DataContract]
[Auditable]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    [Audit]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    [Audit]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to identify the custom attribute on the behavior side by using :

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel,
    InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    var typeOfRequest = request.GetType();

    if (!typeOfRequest.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AuditableAttribute), false).Any())
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the *typeOfRequest* is always coming in as a *{Name = "BufferedMessage" FullName = "System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage"}*

Is there a way that I can infer the type of a message by using the request ?

Note: I have a direct reference to the assembly which holds the contract and service is not referred through wsdl.

Comment: Does your service use SOAP?

Comment: Yes it uses the SOAP Messages to communicate.

Comment: You can inspect the SOAP message to determine what objects are serialized within the request. But why is it that you want to determine the type defined within the message before it has been de-serialized by the service?

Comment: As stated in the problem statement I wanted to read only certain values of the contracts which are decorated by the custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the above problem is not to use a MessageInspector (as in *IDispatchMessageInspector* or *IClientMessageInspector*) instead use a parameter Inspector (as in *IParameterInspector*).

In the BeforeCall Method we can do something like:

```
public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
{

        var request = inputs[0];

        var typeOfRequest = request.GetType();

        if (!typeOfRequest.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```